# How to scroll within a table using watir-scroll

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

I have an application in which there is a dynamic table, rows are loaded only when you scroll up or down. Watir-scroll is scrolling the entire page. Is there anyway I can perform the scrolling within that table?

Comment: I am sure you might be already aware but https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Atleast for me its difficult to think of an solution until unless you  share your HTML /and tried code.

Comment: @rahulrai Yes, I am very much aware of that! But that site is internal and also I don't find any example site which exactly similar to my condition. But I hope you can guess what I am saying. There is table which is inside the webpage and to scroll that table, I will move the mouse and scroll down but don't know how to stimulate the same action via selenium.

Comment: So just to make my understanding Clear, when you are scrolling on page your table in not further loading ? You have some separate vertical scroller inside table ?? Or is it once you click inside table n then scroll on page table will be loading ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making an element scrollable is often done by setting the `overflow` style. It is likely on a `div` that contains the `table`. For example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="overflow:scroll; height:250px;">
      <table>
        <tr height="200px"><td>Cell A</td></tr>
        <tr height="200px"><td>Cell B</td></tr>
        <tr height="200px"><td>Cell C</td></tr>
        <tr height="200px"><td>Cell D</td></tr>
     </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

There are no built-in methods in Watir (at least as of v6.17.0) for scrolling an element. However, there are still some workarounds.

**Set scrollTop**

You can set the scroll position of the element by setting its `scrollTop` property:

```
# Get the element that has the overflow property
div = browser.div                                                                                      

# Scroll to a specific point
div.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = 100;', div) 

# Scroll down a certain amount
div.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop += 50;', div)
```

**Send Keys**

Depending how your application is listening for the scrolled event, setting the `scrollTop` might not trigger the loading of rows. An approach that is more likely to be detected is by sending the `:down` or `:page_down` keyboard keys - ie more like a real user.

It looks like both Watir and Selenium-WebDriver prevent using `#send_keys` for this (throws not interactable errors), so you'll need to use the action builder:

```
# Get the element that has the overflow property
div = browser.div

# Scroll down a bit
browser.wd.action.send_keys(div.wd, :down).perform  
browser.wd.action.send_keys(div.wd, :page_down).perform  

# Scroll to the bottom
browser.wd.action.send_keys(div.wd, :end).perform
```

Comment: You are really a genius! Works like a charm! But this action builder code goes to the stale element problem. It throws the stale element.

Comment: That's strange. Does the application re-create that `div` each time you scroll?

Comment: I don't know where exactly it happens, but it throws the stale element error when I execute `browser.wd.action.send_keys(div.wd, :down).perform  `, As I stated in the question, when I scroll, those rows are coming into the existence(which means it did not exist before or you don't find those elements before you scroll) those elements goes up would disappear. What's appear in the table only exist.

Comment: Well that's strange. Did you go with the scrollTop solution then?