# Scrolling the table horizontally

Tags: ruby, watir

I have this table

[image]

I have to scroll horizontally to click the button as shown below

[image]

This is the HTML code for this element

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="v-grid-scroller v-grid-scroller-horizontal" style="padding-bottom: 17px; height: 0px; width: 1036px; left: 0px; overflow-x: scroll;"><div style="height: 17px; width: 1566.09px;"></div></div>
```

Is there any way I can perform the horizontal scroll using WATIR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to [scrolling vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63714913/1200545), you will need to use JavaScript to horizontally scroll the element. This is done by setting the `scrollLeft` property:

```
# Get the element that has the overflow property
div = browser.div                                                                                      

# Scroll to a specific point
div.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollLeft = 100;', div) 

# Scroll right a certain amount
div.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollLeft += 50;', div)
```

Comment: Works! Can't we create a WATIR method for this? Why can't we create a wrapper method like `browser.div.scroll_left(6times)` and `browser.div.scroll_top(6times)` ?

Comment: Adding some methods would make sense. Though I'm struggling with finding a good/consistent naming with the existing scroll functionality. At any rate, please create a feature request on project so we don't forget. Thanks.